# Density on the square, expected value

Tags: probability, random-variables, random, expectation, geometric-probability

Let $f: [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^{+}$ a density function on the square.

I suppose that the random variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$ has the density f with respect to the lebesgue measure.

I denote $\bar{X}=(\bar{X_1},\bar{X_2})$ the average point in the square.

$E(\bar{X_1})=  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x f(x,y) dx dy$

$E(\bar{X_2})=  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 y f(x,y) dx dy$

Is it true, or not, that any line on the square which countains $\bar{X}$ separates the square into two areas which has the same expected value?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No:

Consider $f(x,y) = g(x)$ where $g$ is a distribution for which the mean is different from the median, and the line $$\left\{ x = EX_1 = \int_0^1 xg(x)dx
\right\}$$

Then both areas
$$
\int_{x>EX_1} f(x,y) dx dy = P(x>EX_1)
\\
\int_{x<EX_1} f(x,y) dx dy = P(x<EX_1)
$$
are different.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is true with some smooth condition on the density function?

Comment: No, my counterexample works even if $g$ is smooth, in which case $f$ is smooth as well.

Comment: Ok, i just realized that even the 1-dimensional case wasn't clear for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you think it works with the median??? (any line of the square which countains the median separate the square into two square of same"size"?

Comment: Hum... it may be possible.